# Ajax chosen wild card search result

Tags: jquery, wildcard, bootstrapper

I am using ajax-chosen for select field of a form.

```
$('#importers_tag').ajaxChosen(
    {
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'POST',

        url : site_url + '/dashboard/load_products'
    },
    {
        generateUrl : function(q) {
            return site_url + '/dashboard/load_products/'
                    + encodeURIComponent($('#importers_tag').val()) //dynamic url to avoid duplicate in result
        },
        loadingImg : baseUrl
                + '/resources/js/plugins/chosen/loading.gif'
    });
```

My query in the ajax request is by the following query

```
$query = $this->db->query('select * from product where product_id not in ('.$not_in.') and product_name like "%'.$q.'%"');
```

But the ajax-chosen select options producing "product_name like '$q%'"

I want to give the select result by wild card on both the sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make this other way around, you can check out http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ and use 
jQuery ajax and sent form data with serialization, on backend side you can handle those parameters and make a clean query, than you can do what ever you like with results.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. But I have used the above method over the codes in many places. I cannot search for another solution. Also my question is to get the wild card search result in ajax-chosen method. Wild card is working only one side like $q%. I need %$q%

Comment: if that is a usual case, you can add an '%' extra in front..could you share some URL would like to test it...

Comment: There is no production URL to share. I can give you ajax-chosen link http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/. In this, on searching "United states" Country from the first example, you have to type "Uni" or "Sta". But I want United states to appear even if I enter "nited".

Comment: that's clear, regarded to this resource seem that you have to change chosen plugin on line ~836 is a function Chosen.prototype.winnow_results in that function search logic has been implemented, so due to that they always get result which starts with entered string...and definitely you can on server side do what ever you like, even if front end sends $q% you always can add prefix %.

Comment: Great. I am in that line. But sorry I am not very good in javascript. Can you please locate me the wildcard symbol there?